# Creating a Script in google apps script to launch a google form

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps

I am trying to create a script where if you change the values in Column D from blank to "Create Something", it will launch a google form.

I tried this code, but nothing happens. Also edited the trigger button, but nothing happens.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // Replace 'YourSheetName' with the actual name of your sheet
  var columnDIndex = 15; // Column D is the 4th column (1-indexed)

  if (e.range.getColumn() == columnDIndex && e.value == 'Create Something') {
    openGoogleForm();
  }
}

function openGoogleForm() {
  var formUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/yourid'; // Replace 'your-form-id' with the actual ID of your form
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formUrl);
  form.createResponse().submit();
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `it will launch a google form` of `I am trying to create a script where if you change the values in Column D from blank to "Create Something", it will launch a google form.` from your showing script and question. Can I ask you about the details of it?

Comment: Hi. I am actually trying to create a Script using google apps script. I have column D and once I put the values or type "Create Something", the Google Form will pop-out or will launch. But the codes that I used isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When a value of `Create Something` is put into column "D" of "Sheet1", you want to open Google Form.

#### Modification points:

- I think that `var columnDIndex = 15; // Column D is the 4th column (1-indexed)` and `e.range.getColumn() == columnDIndex` mean column "O".
- In the case of `e.value == 'Create Something'`, when a value of `Create Something` is put by copying and pasting, the value of `e.value` has no value. Please be careful about this.
- In order to open HTML, it is required to use the installable OnEdit trigger instead of the simple trigger.

When these points are reflected in a sample script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet and save the script. And, **please install the OnEdit trigger to the function `installedOnEdit`**. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#manage_triggers_manually)

And, please set your Google Form URL to `formUrl`.

And, please confirm your sheet name. In this sample, when a value of `Create Something` is put into column "D" of "Sheet1", the script works. Please be careful about this.

```js
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  var { range, value } = e;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() == "Sheet1" && range.columnStart == 4 && !range.isBlank()) { // or if (sheet.getSheetName() == "Sheet1" && range.columnStart == 4 && (value == 'Create Something' || range.getValue() == 'Create Something')) {
    var formUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/{formId}/edit'; // Please set your Google Form URL.
    var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formUrl);
    form.getPublishedUrl();
    var script = `<script>window.open('${form.getPublishedUrl()}', '_blank');google.script.host.close();</script>`;
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(script);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'sample');
  }
}
```

- When you put a value of `Create Something` into column "D" of "Sheet1", a Google Form is opened.
- In this sample, in order to open Google Form, Javascript is used on a dialog.
- In this sample, the Google Form of the public URL is opened. If you want to directly open Google Form please modify the above script as follows.

  ```js
  function installedOnEdit(e) {
    var { range, value } = e;
    var sheet = range.getSheet();
    if (sheet.getSheetName() == "Sheet1" && range.columnStart == 4 && !range.isBlank()) { // or if (sheet.getSheetName() == "Sheet1" && range.columnStart == 4 && (value == 'Create Something' || range.getValue() == 'Create Something')) {
      var formUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/{formId}/edit'; // Please set your Google Form URL.
      var script = `<script>window.open('${formUrl}', '_blank');google.script.host.close();</script>`;
      var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(script);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'sample');
    }
  }
  ```
- If you don't want to check the sheet name, please remove `sheet.getSheetName() == "Sheet1" &&` .

#### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [showModalDialog(userInterface, title)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showModalDialog(Object,String))

### Added:

From your provided Spreadsheet, I noticed that your value of `var formUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/yourid';` is the public URL. From your script, I thought that this URL might be the URL for editing.

In this case, it is required to use my 2nd script. But, from your situation, I'm worried about the installable trigger. So, I added one more sample script including your URL. Please confirm it.

1. Please replace your current script with the following script.
2. Please directly run `installOnEditTrigger()` with the script editor. By this, the installable OnEdit trigger is installed to the function `installedOnEdit`.
3. Please edit a cell of column "D" of "Sheet1". By this, the script is automatically run by the installable OnEdit trigger.

```js
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  var { range, value } = e;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() == "Sheet1" && range.columnStart == 4 && !range.isBlank()) { // or if (sheet.getSheetName() == "Sheet1" && range.columnStart == 4 && (value == 'Create Something' || range.getValue() == 'Create Something')) {
    var formUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/###/viewform'; // Please set your Google Form URL.
    var script = `<script>window.open('${formUrl}', '_blank');google.script.host.close();</script>`;
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(script);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'sample');
  }
}

// Please run this function. By this, the installable trigger is installed to the function "installedOnEdit".
function installOnEditTrigger() {
  const functionName = "installedOnEdit";
  ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().forEach(t => {
    if (t.getHandlerFunction() == functionName) {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(t);
    }
  });
  ScriptApp.newTrigger(functionName).forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onEdit().create();
}
```

Comment: There is an error. It says, 
Error 
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'range' of 'e' as it is undefined.

Comment: @Jong Ramos Thank you for replying. About `There is an error. It says, Error TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'range' of 'e' as it is undefined.`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I guess that you might have directly run `installedOnEdit`. In that case, such an error occurs because of no event object. In my answer, I said that when you put a value of "Create Something" into column "D" of "Sheet1", a Google Form is opened. So, can you put a value into column "D" of "Sheet1"? By the way, you have already installed the OnEdit trigger to the function `installedOnEdit`?

Comment: I actually just copied the codes you sent me and changed the URL

Comment: @Jong Ramos Thank you for replying. About `I actually just copied the codes you sent me and changed the URL`, if you cannot understand my English please tell me.

Comment: I understand. How do I install the OnEdit Trigger?

Comment: @Jong Ramos Thank you for replying. About your new question of `I understand. How do I install the OnEdit Trigger?`, I have already mentioned in my answer. You can see how to install OnEdit trigger at the official document https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#manage_triggers_manually

Comment: That's what I actually did. But still not working.

Comment: @Jong Ramos Thank you for replying. About `That's what I actually did. But still not working.`, I apologize for the inconvenience and my poor English skill. Unfortunately, when I tested my proposed script, the script worked correctly. And, unfortunately, from `But still not working.`, I cannot understand your current situation. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your `But still not working.`? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: here's the link of the sheet that I am working on. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LQGVPb8X5M8956rnpjxAxzC8z8Vv8HcjXnXaF3bY9iA/edit#gid=0

Comment: Kindly try to open the link and see if I made something incorrect. Thanks.

Comment: @Jong Ramos Thank you for replying. I will check it. Please wait for it.

Comment: Okay Thanks. Actually, when I type Create Something in Column D, the google form is not launching or popping-out.

Comment: @Jong Ramos By checking your provided Spreadsheet, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it.

Comment: I don't see your sample script there.

Comment: Oh it works. Thanks! But can you please delete the link or the url of the google form?

Comment: @Jong Ramos Thank you for replying. About `But can you please delete the link or the url of the google form?`, I did it. Please confirm it.

Comment: @Jong Ramos About `Oh it works. Thanks!`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: I dont see the button.

Comment: Can you also help me to get the image of an ASIN from amazon?